# building Dataset - strange behavior on np arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

i'm trying to build a dataset from 'cls_encoding' object (bert output).

```
print (cls_encoding.shape)
(1, 768)
```

i have 30 cls_encoding so i want to make an array with shape (30,768).

when i try:

```
print(cls_encoding[0].shape)
(768,)
```

so if i try to do this:

```
DSlist = []
for x in DS:
  DSlist.append(x[0])
print(np.array(DSlist).shape)
```

i get:

```
(30, 768, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

how can i get from this to the wanted shape (30,768)?

Comment: Make sure every `x` in `DS` has the same shape which is (1, 768).. because I don't think they have

Comment: thank you,the problem was that cls_encoding is from type mxnet.ndarray, x.asnumpy() solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list (with length 30) of arrays where each array has the shape `(1,768)` you could transform that list to an array with the shape `(30,768)` via:

```py
# build a sytetic dataset
DS = []
for i in range(30):
    DS.append(np.array([np.random.rand(768)]))


# transform the list to a array

DS_arr = np.asarray(DS)

print(DS_arr.shape)

DS_arr = np.squeeze(DS_arr)

print(DS_arr.shape)
```

```py
>>> (30, 1, 768)
>>> (30, 768)
```

Comment: Using `concatenate`  (axis=0) or `vstack` would save you the `squeeze` call.